# How to get values from anonymous list to a dictionary?

Tags: c#

Currently have the below code which upon compilation creates an anonymous list. I need to convert that to a standard list type preferably a dictionary. I can't find anything online to do so.

```
_dbService.GetAllOrN().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ has `ToDictionary`.  You could do that instead of calling `Select`.

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
```

Comment: It won't let me accept until 10 minutes have passed but this worked! Thanks.